# Column or globale Variable not found

Tags: errors, db2-midrange

Error msg:

> DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42S22] [IBM][System i Access
> ODBC-stuurprogramma][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Kolom of globale
> variabele AADETX niet gevonden. Details:
> DataSourceKind=Odbc
> DataSourcePath=dsn=I-Make
> OdbcErrors=[Table]

Google translate of the error message:  Column or global variable AADETX not found.

Request:

```
SELECT

A.G1AATX AS Artikel,
A.GIG4NU ATP_aantal_cum,
A.G1HADT BEGIN_periode

FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.V1G1REP A

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 

B.AAAATX AS Artikel,
B.AADATX Artikelgroep,
B.AADETX Artikeltype

FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP 

WHERE B.AADATX <> 'SMEE'
AND B.AADATX <> 'LIJM'
AND B.AADATX <> 'UMEC'
AND B.AADETX ='I'

GROUP BY AAAATX
) B on B.AAAATX = A.G1AATX

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 

C.ELAATX AS Artikel,
C.ELCXST Status

FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VOELREP

WHERE C.ELCXST IN ('A',' ')

GROUP BY ELAATX
) C on C.ELAATX = A.G1AATX

WHERE A.G1AATX = '4022-480-9858'
```

The column AADETX the error reffers to does exist.
If i look it up in just the table i can find the specifiek data.

I'm trying to fix the duplicates errors i got from the request below:

First attempt:

```
SELECT

A.G1AATX As Artikel, 
A.G1G4NU ATP_aantal_cum,
A.G1HADT Begindatum_periode,
B.AADETX I

FROM

MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.V1G1REP A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP B on B.AAAATX=A.G1AATX
LEFT OUTER JOIN MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VOELREP C on C.ELAATX=A.G1AATX

WHERE B.AADATX <> 'SMEE'
AND B.AADATX <> 'LIJM'
AND B.AADATX <> 'UMEC'
AND C.ELCXST IN ('A',' ')
AND B.AADETX ='I'
AND A.G1AATX = '4022-480-9858'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community, please tag your DBMS version included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this fragment of your code,

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 

B.AAAATX AS Artikel,
B.AADATX Artikelgroep,
B.AADETX Artikeltype

FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP 

WHERE B.AADATX <> 'SMEE'
AND B.AADATX <> 'LIJM'
AND B.AADATX <> 'UMEC'
AND B.AADETX ='I'

GROUP BY AAAATX
) B on B.AAAATX = A.G1AATX
```

you have references like `B.AADATX`, `B.AADATX`, `B.AADETX`, which are invalid, because there is no table or alias called `B` defined in that context.  The `B` name is assigned to the derived table itself but *inside* the derived table, the `B` reference is invalid.

To resolve the issue, either assign the `B` alias to `MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP`:

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 

B.AAAATX AS Artikel,
B.AADATX Artikelgroep,
B.AADETX Artikeltype

FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP B  -- << here

WHERE B.AADATX <> 'SMEE'
AND B.AADATX <> 'LIJM'
AND B.AADATX <> 'UMEC'
AND B.AADETX ='I'

GROUP BY AAAATX
) B on B.AAAATX = A.G1AATX
```

or remove `B.` from all column references inside the `B` derived table:

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 

AAAATX AS Artikel,
AADATX Artikelgroep,
AADETX Artikeltype

FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP 

WHERE AADATX <> 'SMEE'
AND AADATX <> 'LIJM'
AND AADATX <> 'UMEC'
AND AADETX ='I'

GROUP BY AAAATX
) B on B.AAAATX = A.G1AATX
```

The same goes for the `C` derived table further in your code.

Additionally, both `B` and `C` rename the columns they are pulling from their respective underlying tables.  Therefore, you must reference those columns using the names they are exposed as.  Therefore this:

```
on B.AAAATX = A.G1AATX
```

should actually be this:

```
on B.Artikel = A.G1AATX
```

And this:

```
on C.ELAATX = A.G1AATX
```

should be rewritten like this:

```
on C.Artikel = A.G1AATX
```

(I was in the middle of adding these last two when [nbk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/190821/nbk) posted an answer pointing them out.)

Comment: I removed all B and C from "INSIDE" the subselect but it still gives me this error DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC-stuurprogramma][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0122 - Kolom AADATX of expressie in SELECT-lijst is ongeldig.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=I-Make
    OdbcErrors=[Table] Also changed the names outside the subselect but can't yet tell if or not this was a problem, in the past this never gave me a problem, but good advice none the less.

Answer (score 1):

You subselect BN has no such column B.AADETX  anymore it is called now B.Artikeltype.

If you use an alias in a subselect, this will be the column name you can address it with outside of the subselect

```
SELECT
    A.G1AATX AS Artikel,
    A.GIG4NU ATP_aantal_cum,
    A.G1HADT BEGIN_periode
FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.V1G1REP A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        B.AAAATX AS Artikel,
        B.AADATX Artikelgroep,
        B.AADETX Artikeltype

    FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VIAAREP B

    WHERE B.AADATX <> 'SMEE'
    AND B.AADATX <> 'LIJM'
    AND B.AADATX <> 'UMEC'
    AND B.AADETX ='I'

    GROUP BY AAAATX
) B on B.Artikeltype = A.G1AATX

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        C.ELAATX AS Artikel,
        C.ELCXST Status
    FROM MIFA.VIS#MOGEM.VOELREP C

    WHERE C.ELCXST IN ('A',' ') 
    GROUP BY ELAATX
) C on C.ELAATX = A.G1AATX
WHERE A.G1AATX = '4022-480-9858'
```

Comment: I removed all B and C from "INSIDE" the subselect but it still gives me this error DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC-stuurprogramma][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0122 - Kolom AADATX of expressie in SELECT-lijst is ongeldig.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=I-Make
    OdbcErrors=[Table]

Comment: @JeffreyHazeleger: That's a different issue. You are selecting three columns in `B` but grouping only by one of them. You can't select the other two by a simple reference. Either add them to `GROUP BY` as well or put each inside an aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks that solved that now i get the next error: DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42S22] [IBM][System i Access ODBC-stuurprogramma][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Kolom of globale variabele GIG4NU niet gevonden.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=I-Make
    OdbcErrors=[Table] Tried removing the A. but that didn't help me out.

Comment: @JeffreyHazeleger: We are now far beyond the scope of your original question and even if we weren't, this last issue is hard to solve without knowing more about your tables.  On the face of it, you may actually have an incorrect column name this time. In any event, you may need to post a new question if you are unable to resolve this on your own.

Comment: I corrected the problen with the aliases, but for further debugginbg we need ti know your tables and i can't see any gig4nu in your actual code

Comment: @nbk: It's there near the beginning of the query, second column in the main SELECT.

Comment: Thank you all GIG4NU has to be G1G4NU a smaal but important typo.